# CakePHP .actions button label

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I started coding in CakePHP lately and love the quick and easy interface framework it provides. I have one model that has kind of a long name and it is causing UI issues with the Action buttons. When I am in the CRUD index page for the model the text within the anchor tag displays outside of the background image used to make the button. Here is a link to a screenshot for what I am talking about...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IROA5.jpg

Does anyone know how to modify the CSS for this so that it will word wrap where necessary?

EDIT for Nunuser:
Here is the HTML code for the button:

```
<div class="actions">
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/users/add">New User</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user_types">List User Types</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user_types/add">New User Type</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user_statuses">List User Statuses</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user_statuses/add">New User Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="/region_program_offices">List Region Program Offices</a></li>
        <li><a href="/region_program_offices/add">New Region Program Office</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS Style for the button:

```
.actions li {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0 0 0.5em;
  padding:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
cake.generic.css
* {
}
cake.generic.css
ul, li {
  margin:0 12px;
}
cake.generic.css (line 66)
Inherited frombody
body {
  font-family:'lucida grande', verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:90%;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the screenshot that the view was baked and the css used there is the default. To make it easier to help you, please inspect that button's code (with firebug or the like) and post the current css for that button as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16366165/edit) to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default stylesheet is called `cake.generic.css` and is located in `app/webroot/css/`. Remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `.actions li` at line 498.

Comment: I tried editing many of the different CSS entries within cake.generic.css using the max-width parameter, but all of them only affected the width of the button-like background image, not the text. Did you have a particular line in mind to edit?